# Selecting nested html elements using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, html-table

I am new to selenium `(PYTHON)` and stuck at one point and need help from experts.
My html is some thing like this:

```
    <div id='d3_tree'>
       <svg>
         <g transform="translate(20,50)>
            <g class='node'>
                <foreignobject></foreignobject>
                <original_title>
                   <table>
                       <tbody>
                          <tr>
                              <td>t1key1</td>
                              <td>t1val1</td>  
                          </tr> 
                          <tr>
                              <td>t1key2</td>
                              <td>t1val2</td>  
                          </tr> 
                          <tr>
                              <td>t1key3</td>
                              <td>t1val3</td>  
                          </tr> 
                       </tbody> 
                   </table>
                </original_title> 
            </g> 
            <g class='node pe_node'>
                <foreignobject></foreignobject>
                <original_title>
                   <table>
                       <tbody>
                          <tr>
                              <td>t2key1</td>
                              <td>t2val1</td>  
                          </tr> 
                          <tr>
                              <td>t2key2</td>
                              <td>t2val2</td>  
                          </tr> 
                          <tr>
                              <td>t2key3</td>
                              <td>t2val3</td>  
                          </tr> 
                       </tbody> 
                   </table>
                </original_title> 
            </g>
            <g class='node pe_node'>
                <foreignobject></foreignobject>
                <original_title>
                   <table>
                       <tbody>
                          <tr>
                              <td>t3key1</td>
                              <td>t3val1</td>  
                          </tr> 
                          <tr>
                              <td>t3key2</td>
                              <td>t3val2</td>  
                          </tr> 
                          <tr>
                              <td>t3key3</td>
                              <td>t3val3</td>  
                          </tr> 
                       </tbody> 
                   </table>
                </original_title> 
            </g> 
         </g>
       </svg>

</div>
```

what I need is all the elements of having class node.pe_node and inside every node.pe node element I need the text of third row second column of table. (t2val3 t3val3)

I am able to get the elements having class node.pe_node

```
pe_nodes = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".node.vm.node_pe")
```

Now I am iterating over the pe_nodes to get the the value of third column by

```
  for node in pe_nodes:
     petext = node.find_element(By.XPATH, "//tr[3]/td[2]").text //not working
     petext = node.find_element(By.XPATH, "//tr[3]/td[2]").get_text() //not working
```

Can any one please guide me as how to get the required text? Is there a way refer the table column inside every node element?

Comment: You miss a quote mark in the third line, after `translate`

Comment: I would use @JakubM. example, beatiful soup is very easy to use when parsing html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the way

```
name = node.find_element_by_xpath(".//tr[2]/td[2]")text
```

Comment: Dot text missing?

Answer (score 1):

```
import bs4

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)
node_pe = [s for s in soup.find_all('g')
           if 'pe_node' in s.attrs.get('class', [])]
col_texts = [s.find_all('tr')[2].find_all('td')[1].text
             for s in node_pe]
print col_texts
```

It produces:

```
[u't2val3', u't3val3']
```